# Force reusing roles that bootstrap made with CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When I do `bootstrap` by cdk

this error occurs.

It means there are some same name role remains.

Because I once did the bootstrap.

In this case, I can delete `CDKToolkit` from cloudformaiton and re-run again.

However my account have no right to delete role.

If so, is there any way to reuse existing role?

```
10:27:18 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | ImagePublishingRole
cdk-hnb659fds-image-publishing-role-31441111111111-ap-northeast-1 already exists

10:27:23 | DELETE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | FilePublishingRole
API: iam:DeleteRole User: arn:aws:iam::31441111111111:user/myuser is not authorized to perform: iam:DeleteRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-myuser31441111111111-ap-northeast-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:DeleteRole action

10:27:23 | DELETE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | CloudFormationExecutionRole
API: iam:DetachRolePolicy User: arn:aws:iam::31441111111111:user/myuser is not authorized to perform: iam:DetachRolePolicy on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-314
411397247-ap-northeast-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:DetachRolePolicy action

10:27:23 | DELETE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | LookupRole
API: iam:DeleteRolePolicy User: arn:aws:iam::31441111111111:user/myuser is not authorized to perform: iam:DeleteRolePolicy on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-31441
1397247-ap-northeast-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:DeleteRolePolicy action
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little convoluted, but you can manually deploy the `CDKToolkit` and use the import feature to import existing roles into the stack.

Use the following to get `CDKToolkit` template instead of letting `cdk` deploy it.

```
cdk bootstrap --show-template
```

Then use CloudFormation UI to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) it.

[image]

It will ask you for the name/ARN of any resource that can be imported.

You may have to modify the template a bit to remove resources that can't or shouldn't be imported. Once you're done importing existing resources, deploy the full unmodified template again.

Comment: Thankyou !! as you mentioned it is a bit convoluted. However this techniques can work for many situation.